# PHP detection of iPad to prevent file upload

Tags: php, ios, ipad, file-upload, upload

So apparently the iPad does not allow you to upload images to a server via the browser ... so I need to be able to detect that the user is using an iPad and then hide the ability for them to "browse" for a file.

Is there any particular best practice for such a thing via PHP?

Comment: iOS supports image uploading since iOS 6.

Comment: If the iPad does not support file uploads, I would expect the browser to NOT show file upload form elements in the first place. Or render them unclickable.

Comment: I totally agree, Sven ... but it still shows up.

Comment: Then "It's not a bug. It's amazing!" :)

Comment: You are sure you still use iOS 5? Banning iOS 6 which has the ability wouldn't be nice. Detecting the version of the iOS and the Safari Mobile browser complicates the problem. Ignoring the problem because users will update to iOS 6 might be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check the user agent.

```
$isiPad = (bool) strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad');
```

Comment: how accurate is user agent nowadays?

Comment: It's irrelevant. It's iPad. Average user will not be able to change user agent on iPad :) Yet, above solution is wrong as file upload is supported since iOS 6

Comment: Yes, but there are plenty of people that do NOT have iOS6 ... that's Chrome mentality. We still live in a world that supports IE.

Answer (score 0):

I'd ignore that myself, but if you really want, you check UserAgent using `get_browser()`. Please note you need `browse.cap` file installed and PHP pointed to it - see docs for details.

Alternatively inspect it by hand: `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`.

Docs for `get_browser()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: get_browser() is just an enhanced user agent sniffing - and this itself is wrong.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong in using user agent for such simple task, nor any arguments of your to back your "wrong" claim. It'd be time waste to write anything more complex in the OP's case.

Comment: get_browser() is way too complicated to set up in the first place. "Get a current browsecap.ini file" is the first obstacle. The link mentioned on the php page says: "This project will be closing at year's end." (2012). Second is to get it installed. It has to be done either in php.ini or httpd.conf - no .htaccess magic. Third: The information gathered is mostly wrong. Server side client detection doesn't work.

Comment: Sure. If you are not root or your hosting does not offer it then it is a problem. browse.cap project **might** go EOL, it is not set yet, but still I think that some basic checks based on user agent are sufficient for OP's task. It's not rocket since. We even wasted too much time discussing it than it is worth. Unless most of my users were iPad'ers I'd personally just add a note to the `<form>` to point that uploading is not working prior iOS 6 and that's it or do this based on User agent - hence my answer.